# history.go(-1) function not working for dropdown

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i am using the function history.go(-1) function on my button to go back. but i am getting a prob in value selected in dropdown.

the sourceview is showing the original value selected but on UI its showing the previous value

means when i click on back button,

UI shows the same value but when i view the source code then the selected value is the same that need to be appear

for example

suppose my dropdown has data in format MM/YYYY
first i select 02/2010 and then after that i select 04/2010
now when i click on back button having onclick ="history.go(-1)"

then the value in dropdown remains the same i.e 04/2010 but when i see the source code, then for dropdown the selected value shows as 02/2010.

I cant understand this UI behavior. can any one help me to rectify this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is legitimate browser behavior that show the last state of the page instead of reloading it.

You can force the page to always reload by having this in your code behind:

```
Response.Expires = -1;
Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching();
Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(false);
Response.CacheControl ="no-cache";
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```